# What's the meaning of "s'emballer"?

Tags: sens, verbes, registre-familier

I hear this verb quite often. Does it mean that "I've made a mistake"? Or is it really contextual? Any idea of its frequent contextual usage?

Comment: Have you tried looking in a dictionary? What did you find?

Comment: I have checked wiktionnaire: "S’exalter d’une façon irréfléchie et excessive pour ou contre quelqu’un ou quelque chose" OR "S'accélérer, hors de tout contrôle, en parlant d'une machine qui ne peut plus être arrêtée"

Comment: Does this answer satisfy you or do you have additional questions? *Emballer* has several meanings, and can be pronominal or not. Maybe you could give a sentence where you don't understand its meaning.

Comment: There's another meaning that I didn't find on the wiktionary but that is used, mostly by teens: "*emballer*" can mean "to kiss", so "*s'emballer*" in this context would be "*s'embrasser*". (ex: "*Je les ai vu dans les toilettes, ils étaient en train de s'emballer!*")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the verb was directed to you, then it most probably meant that you were getting too excited about something and that you needed to calm down.. But indeed some context would help.

E.g. "T'emballe pas" means "Calm down".

Comment: Yes, the slang usage here, should answer the question.